# express route with param overriding the static route

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have a code like below

```
app.get('/all', callback2);
app.get('/:id', callback);
```

`/:id` is overriding the route `/all`.

Comment: If you're on express 4+ the order you declare them in matters.  Also, semantically most folks would not have a /all route, just use / as the equivalent list

Comment: Does it work if you flip the order?  If not, it's probably how express parses route parameters.

Comment: @Paul This is the response {
message: "Cast to ObjectId failed for value "all" at path "_id"",
name: "CastError",
kind: "ObjectId",
value: "all",
path: "_id"
}

Comment: @JimBaldwin Flipping the order isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I can think of, other than avoiding the use of potentially ambiguous routes, is to implement one route like this:

```
app.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
    if (req.params.id === 'all') {
        // do what you would do for /all
    } else {
        // do what you do for /:id
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea.. but I renamed my 'all' route to '/' and fixed the issue.

Comment: Since that's also the de facto standard, that's probably a good result.

Answer (score 1):

a good way of solving this problem even though it isnt the best is to define

```
app.get('/all', callback2);
```

before the

```
app.get('/:id', callback);
```

now the router would first check the first route before the other ones